# Android: Equalizer - getNumberOfBands()

Tags: android, equalizer

According with http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/audiofx/Equalizer.html#getNumberOfBands(), we can see the description of method getNumberOfBands() - **Gets the number of frequency bands supported by the Equalizer engine**.

Do this depend of device or android version???

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it most probably depends on **Device**.

Answer (score 1):

**Frequency depends on hardware So according to my knowledge it must depend on Device.**

And you can also test(check) it by upgrading your phone. test number of bands before upgrade and after upgrade if NumberOfBands are same then I am absolutely right.

Answer (score 0):

I was curios about this too. But I'm not that sure if this depends on the device type. I tested  this on a Samsung Galaxy S8+ and on a Samsung J5, and on both devices I get 5 bands of frequency, and I don't know why. Another thing is on the J5 in the Google Play Music app I have 7 freq bands, and on the SGS8+ in the same app(Google Play Music) there are 9 freq bands. I don't know why but if anyone knows why this is happening please let us know.