# Can i set the band numbers of a equalizer in android app or the hardware could limit me?

Tags: android

there. I'm working in a project for developing a audio equializer in Android, the client requires to work with a 31 bands equalizer, is this possible?

Thanks for your answers

Comment: According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14639085/android-equalizer-getnumberofbands) hw can be a barrier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible but not with Android Equalizer API. You can use [gStreamer](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/) multimedia framework. It has Android NDK integration and it has built-in [plugin](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-good-plugins/html/gst-plugins-good-plugins-equalizer-nbands.html) that support up to 64 channel equalizer. But implementation is a little complicated. I hope this helps.

Comment: did you seccuss on 31 bands equalizer?